# How to get compact html code in page source?

Tags: html, django

I use many tags in my template, so my code after previewing the page has a lot of empty spaces.

How can I get the code compact like on the example below:

[image]

```
[...]
startsWith",function(a){return a?a:function(e,c){if(null==this)throw new TypeError("The 'this' value for String.prototype.startsWith must not be null or undefined");if(e instanceof RegExp)throw new TypeError("First argument to String.prototype.startsWith must not be a regular expression");var b=this+"";e+="";for(var f=b.length,d=e.length,h=Math.max(0,Math.min(c|0,b.length)),g=0;g<d&&h<f;)if(b[h++]!=e[g++])return!1;return g>=d}});google.arwt=function(a){a.href=document.getElementById(a.id.substring(a.id.startsWith("vcs")?3:1)).href;return!0};(function(){var g=function(a,b){this.g=a===e&&b||"";this.i=f};g.prototype.l=!0;g.prototype.j=function(){return this.g.toString()};var h=/^(?:(?:https?|mailto|ftp):|[^:/?#]*(?:[/?#]|$))/i,f={},e={};var l=/^((market|itms|intent|itms-appss):\/\/)/i,m=function(a){var b;a instanceof g||!l.te
[...]
```

The code after choosing the *view page source* option does not contain any spaces. Why does Google and many other websites use this solution and what is its proper name?

Comment: It is called [Minifying](https://www.google.com/search?q=minify&oq=minify) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/performance/why-minify-javascript-code/):

> Minification, also known as minimization, is the process of removing
>   all unnecessary characters from JavaScript source code without
>   altering its functionality. This includes the removal of whitespace,
>   comments, and semicolons, along with the use of shorter variable names
>   and functions. Minification of JavaScript code results in compact file
>   size.

Django also provide a template tag for removing whitespace from the HTML, the tag is [spaceless](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless).

From the Docs:

> Removes whitespace between HTML tags. This includes tab characters and
>   newlines. Only space between tags is removed – not space between tags and text